# What is this transaction, I did not make

Tags: transactions

Can someone explain what has happened here?  I mined a block of 50 a while back, then I recently made a payment of .31 BTC.  Why is the other 49.69 also in the transaction?  This extra transaction does not show up in my wallet, but if I take an old backup and let it update, it does show up and the total block of 50 is missing.

https://blockchain.info/address/14sDPWsDWUdQCXWpJ4YVQYSxx9TFQh9STt

Comment: Ok, this is reassuring assuming this is an example of a change block.  In this case, how do I add this address into my wallet so that the change shows up back in my wallet when restoring from a backup?  Using the Bitcoin-qt client.

Comment: The address was automatically added to your wallet, it's just hidden and doesn't appear in the "Receive" tab.  But it will be included when you back up wallet.dat.  In fact, bitcoin-qt pre-generates 100 addresses or so, so the address is probably already in your last backup.

Comment: "I mined a block of 50 a while back" :) That is what makes Bitcoin so awesome

Comment: The really awesome thing is that I bought $1,800 worth of software for that .31 BTC.